# How to recognise whether form is modified or not in extjs4

Tags: forms, extjs4

I am working in extjs4. I am having form with multiple textboxes,radio buttons and some more elements.Suppose i clicked on modify form. If user made some editing in form,then i want to display message box window in order to ask confirmation of saving of changes that user has made.If user closes form without any modifications,then that messagebox should not be appear.I was trying to use dirtychange event of form as-

```
me.getForm().on('dirtychange', function(form, isDirty) {
             console.log(form.events); 
             if( isDirty ) {
                    isChanged=true;
                }
                else {
                    isChanged=false;
                }
            });
```

But its setting isChanged variable to always true though form is not modified.
So how to identify whether form is modified or not so that i can display confirmation message box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ext.data.Model-property-dirty](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-property-dirty) to determine if a record has been modified.

```
form.getRecord().dirty
```

If your record is dirty without you making any modifications, you can try this to find which field is dirty.

```
        if (form.isDirty()) {
            var fields = form.getForm().getFields().items;
            for (var i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
                if (fields[i].isDirty()) {
                    if (Ext.isDefined(fields[i].name)) {
                        alert(fields[i].name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanx for reply sir..Actually sir i tried as - me.getForm().on('dirtychange', function(form, isDirty) {
        console.log(form.events); 
     if( isDirty ) {
               isChanged=true;
           }
           else {
               isChanged=false;
           }
       }); But its setting isChanged value always to true. So what corrections i need to do?

Comment: Well, if you have not changed anything on the form then dirty should be false. Have you tried finding out which field is dirty? see my edit above.

Comment: I followed way you suggested. But its giving error as "TypeError: form.getForm is not a function
[Break On This Error]  
var fields = form.getForm().getFields().items;"

Comment: Actually sir i think problem is during modify form, form is loaded along with its records. So may be its giving always true. So what i need to do in this case?